# Android: after installing an APK, the open button is disabled

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I read in so many places that the problem is related to the manifest and the definition of the first activity. It seems that I'm doing fine but still the open button, after installing the APK, is disabled and I don't see the icon on the device

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.example.com"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DateSelectorActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: and if You don´t see the icon...how do You can be sure it is installed?

Comment: When I click the apk attachment (email), the installation window opens up and I click install, there is a progress for it and then a message saying it was installed but the open button is disabled. Also I see the app in settings -> apps

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="www.example.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Here, you are saying that this activity will **only** be launched if:

- the `Intent` has an action of `MAIN` or `VIEW`, **and**
- the `Intent` has the categories of `LAUNCHER` or `BROWSABLE`, **and**
- the `Intent` has a `Uri` with a scheme of `http` and a host of `www.example.com`

The home screen launcher and Settings app will not be creating such an `Intent`, and so they cannot launch this activity.

Either:

- Remove the `VIEW`, `BROWSABLE`, and `<data>` portions of what you have, or
- Move those into a **separate** `<intent-filter>`:

  ```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"/>
  </intent-filter>
  ```

Multiple `<intent-filter>` elements represent an `OR` operation: an `Intent` that matches the first filter **or** the second filter will work for this activity.

Comment: after expends couples of hours, finally i got solution, thanks @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but maybe caused by different reason.
Running following command line worked:

```
adb uninstall com.company.mayapp
```